systemd: Failed to attach to cgroup...No such file or directory
OS
Ubuntu-22.04
Kernel-version
6.2.0-39-generic
systemd --version
systemd 249 (249.11-0ubuntu3.12)
Problem description: From a perl script I am trying to stop and start myservice, this script has no changes and was working fine in systemd 237 / ubuntu 18.04 machines.
Commands in that script are...
/bin/systemctl stop myservice.service
/bin/systemctl start myservice.service

The script is able to successfully stop the service but it could not successfully start it and am seeing below error message.
Apr 26 08:18:27 myhost systemd[11189]: ovt-myservice.service: Failed to attach to cgroup /system.slice/system-ovt\x2dmyservice.slice/ovt-myservice.service: No such file or directory
Apr 26 08:18:27 myhost systemd[11189]: ovt-myservice.service: Failed at step CGROUP spawning /usr/share/fold/systemd/ovt-myservice.sh: No such file or directory
Apr 26 08:18:27 myhost systemd[1]: ovt-myservice.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=219/CGROUP

